# ReCAPTCHA in CI Testing

Tags: recaptcha

I am looking for a way to run tests on new user creation.  The new user process has a ReCaptcha in it and (obviously) tests are bots so I have created a work around I don't like.

On the server I look for a new user with a specific name.  When I see this user, I ignore the CAPTCHA and let it process normally.  This is not good because I do not care for bypass logic being built into a server.

The E2E test even responds to the email that the server sends.

The question is:  Is there a test reCaptcha that I can use when running tests whose query/response is not publically known but known only to me?  e.g. Can I make this a repeatable test?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Not sure if this was available back when the question was originally asked, but Google now includes specific test keys in their reCaptcha FAQs:

[image]
https://developers.google.com/recaptcha/docs/faq#id-like-to-run-automated-tests-with-recaptcha-v2-what-should-i-do